# micro-frameworks for php development

Tags: php

There are numerous frameworks developed for `php` like Zend,Symphony etc.
Frameworks should speeds up development, performance is a secondary concern.

But my question is :

> What is micro-framework?Do micro-frameworks have special advantages?

thanks.

Comment: **Micro-framework** – *noun* – A framework that is "smaller" than other "bigger" frameworks; often meaning that there's less it *can* do and consequently less the developer needs to learn or perhaps write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microframe works are libraries that helps you in building applications that are concise, extensible and testable.

For example [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) is one micro-framework that has the best support of modern PHP programming techniques, is developed in sync with Symfony2, unit-tested, well documented and provides possibility to introduce 3rd party libraries through a very good DI-container mechanism.

In my opinion this framework is best for anything that does not need extensive caching, user-managing, heavy database interaction or security.